# windows XP: DNS query speed

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I solved a problem today, but I do not know if my reasoning is correct.

I have a server 2003 (S-2003) configured as active directory server and DNS server.

The pc clients, all with windows xp pro, are configured with static IP addresses in the domain active directory managed by S-2003.

By hypothesis, say that the IP of S-2003 is 10.10.10.1

The server S-2003 is a database server that is used by LAN users through Internet Explorer by going to a web page.
So that, users can access at the database server portal or writing in IE 10.10.10.1 or the name `http://plutoweb` configured in the local DNS server S.2003.

Now, this system has worked for several months, until a few days ago a user could not access the database server.

Thus, from the user's PC I tried a "nslookup plutoweb" and, strangely, nslookup relay the answer of the google dns server (8.8.8.8).

I expected the name to be resolved by the DNS 10.10.10.1 instead.

So I found that in the TCP / IP address of the user's PC was configured as the preferred DNS IP 10.10.10.1 and DNS as an alternative to google (8.8.8.8)

Removing the IP 8.8.8.8 from local TCP/IP settings of pc, the web page of the database server opens without problems.

Now, I do not know if my deduction is correct, but it is as if the resolution of the name was incorrect because the dns to google dns was faster than the local S-2003.

Something wrong with this conclusion do you think?

best regards,

max

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP dns sometimes ask not a first server, even if it working OK.
I don't know why Windows do this (this is undocumented I think) but I know what is solution - Microsoft published it [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320760)

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so.  The reason is because it should try the preferred one first and not move to the next until the first fails.

Perhaps you need this patch http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286834/EN-US ?

Apparently there is a bug in older OS like XP that will cause the preferred to not be queried first, but I do not think it is a response speed issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is 10.10.10.1 a DNS?
Were you using google as a secondary for a reason ?

I would update host files from gpo, would be safer and stop this issue from happening in the future.

I don't see how 8.8.8.8 can be faster than your local server either.
Best of luck